# JQuery: Iterating through table rows for 2 specific cells

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a total JQuery newbie and I have been researching this for the past 2 days but my brain is now fried.

Here is what I have:

A table that has a certain amount of rows (like an online store's cart)

I do not want the last row (since that contains cart total) and I do not want the first row (which are the column headers)

Here is what I want:

On document load, I want to go through each row of that table (except first and last) and grab (for example) the first column and last column, pass those values to a web service, and have the web service return a value to put in another column's text box of that row

the table structure is as follows:

```
<table id="blahzayblahgrdItems">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>product</td>
<td>req.ship date</td>
<td>est.ship date(input textbox)</td>
<td>price</td>
<td>qty</td>
<td>subtotal</td>
</td>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I'm trying to grab the values from the Product column and the QTY column to pass to webservice and populate the EST. Ship Date column with whats returned from the web service

In code, I've tried something like

```
$(function()
{
var partID;
var qty;

$("table[id*=grdItems] tbody tr").each(function() {})
)
```

However, I'm drawing a blank on getting the actual quantity and product to pass to my webservice.  I've tried different variations of code and throwing an alert box to see whats getting returned but I'm seeing headers, pieces of the table data, the full table data, etc.  Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Is your table missing the tr's?

Comment: whoops ,the tr.'s are not missing, I just forgot to put them up top... editing

Comment: I've added a jsfiddle example that is using an actual json call.  Don't forget to mark the answer that best answers your question by clicking the check mark next to the answer.  Too many new users don't know they should be doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be a little easier to put a class (like `info`) on the first and last rows (especially for styling) and do the following.

Updated jsfiddle with working example using jsfiddle's json echo:

http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/fNwvX/3/

```
// add a class to first and last tr to make formatting a little nicer as well
$('#blahzayblahgrdItems tr:first,#blahzayblahgrdItems tr:last').addClass('info');
// loop over each one except the ones with class
$('#blahzayblahgrdItems tr:not(.info)').each(function() {
    var $prod = $('td:eq(0)', this);
    var $sub = $('td:eq(5)', this);

    var result = $prod.text() + '-' + $sub.text();     // do your ajax with these values
    $.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
      $prod.text(data.val1);  // depends on your system
      $sub.text(data.val2);   // depends on your system
    });



});​
```

Comment: Here is an updated example that prob better shows the data being changed to different values: http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/fNwvX/5/

Comment: I will try your solution once I figure out how to get the class into the <tr>... It's currently in an ASP datagrid view

Comment: Off the top of my head I don't recall how to do it in a datagrid however it is quite easy to do in jquery.. I am updating my answer for you.

Comment: About to try that now, thanks.  I'm going to assume that one of those tr:first should be a tr:last ?

Comment: thanks.. the classes are in and looping correctly.. however I'm running into a small bind... I'm doing a simple alert to make sure I have the correct values being passed before I do any ajax calling.  The product comes out fine.. but the qty gives me a blank value.  Being that what's in the TD that's passing back the blank is a textbox rather than a label, I tried to use .val() instead of .text() but still no dice.  Any ideas?

Comment: This will return the quantity assuming there is only one input int he TD. `$('td:eq(4) input',this).val()`  I'd usually probably put a class on it and do this `$('td:eq(4) input.qty',this).val()`

Comment: Thank you.  That worked.  One last issue and I think I will be good to go.  I'm trying to use that same technique to write the value to a textbox in another TD on that row but isn't working.    $("td:eq(3) input",this).val(data.d) but that does not write anything to the input field there (it's the only one).  I can get it to write using $("input[id*=txtEstShipDate]").val(data.d) which works but this is written to every td that has that input id on each row.  Is there a better way to restrict the update to just that row instead of all rows?

Comment: Are you sure it is in the 4th td?

Comment: It is 0 based so estimated ship date is `td:eq(2) input`.  If you only have 1 input on the entire row you can easily just do `$('input', this).val('your value'); `

Comment: Yes. In the HTML markup when I view source, I have the <tr> then <td /><td /><td /><td /><td /><td /><td /><td /><td /><td />   There are input boxes in the 4th and 5th td that I would like to put the data in.

Comment: To make it easier on yourself put a class on your textboxes:  `$('input.estship', this).val('your val');`

Comment: I've added the class to the textbox but no dice.. no information going into that input field

Comment: You must have some other issue. I am updating an input here:  http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/fNwvX/10/  I'd suggest you open a new question.

Comment: I got it... I didn't realize you were storing that whole td before manipulating it.  Working well.  I wish I could +1 your comments here as well.  Thank you for all your help.  It is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Get your buddies to vote it up!  Kidding, glad to help and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Set a class for each row you want to parse and do this:

```
var partID = $("tr.some_class td")[4].text();
var qty = $("tr.some_class td")[5].text();
```